# set background image to a specified page with @page selector

Tags: php, html, pdf, selector, mpdf

i would to create a pdf file from html with mpdf library. i would to set a background image just to 2'nd page of rendered pdf(not all pages). i use the following code:

```
$mpdf=new mPDF(''); 
$html = '
    <body>
    <style>
      @page {
       background: url("../mpdf60/bg1.jpg") 50% 0 no-repeat;
     }
    </style>

    <div style="margin-bottom:50px">&nbsp;</div>
    <div align="center" style=" margin-bottom:350px"><img src="../mpdf60/pdffirst1.jpg" height="100" width="190" alt=""></div>

    <pagebreak />
    <div>
    </div>
    </body>';
```

in this code the background image set on all pages of rendered pdf(with @page selector).

how can i set the background image just for one page(2'nd page)? thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://mpdf.github.io/paging/using-page.html#named-page-selectors), mPDF supports named @page selectors, so you could do this:

```
<style>
  @page second {
    background: url("../mpdf60/bg1.jpg") 50% 0 no-repeat;
  }
</style>
```

and then:

```
div.second {
  page: second;
}
```

and then your second page should be within a div with a `second` class. Look at the example given at the link with Chapter.